# real numbers, constant symbols in first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, real-numbers, constants

I have this exercise in my book on first order logic:

> Let's work out a language for elementary trigonometry. To get you
> started, let us suggest that you start off with lots of constant
> symbols- one for each real number. It is tempting to use the symbol 7
> to stand for the number seven, but this runs into problems. (Do you
> see why this is illegal? 7, 77, 7/3, ...) Now, what functions would
> you like to discuss? Think of symbols for them. What are the arities
> of you function symbols? Do not forget that you need symbols for
> addition and multiplication! What relation symbols would you like to
> use?

What symbols should I use for the real numbers? I can't use 7 because 7 is contained in 77 and constant symbols can't be properly contained in other symbols. I also have the problem that irrational number have an infinite non-repeating sequence of decimals, and constant symbols have to be finite? How do I solve this?

Is there a way to choose the constant symbols for the real numbers?

Comment: What book are you reading? A first order description of real numbers does not include a symbol for each real number. In fact, the only constant symbols in the language of the reals should be $0$ and $1$ representing the additive and multiplicative identities, respectively.

Comment: @JohnDouma A friendly introduction to mathematic logic, by Christopher C. Leary and Lars Kristiansen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a circular clock face with one hand. Let $[0,2\pi)$ be the positions of the hand where $0$ is the point where the hand points to $12:00$ and the hand moves clockwise with increasing angle.

We know that $[0,2\pi)$ is uncountable so let $\phi:\mathbb R\to [0,2\pi)$ be a bijection. For $r\in\mathbb R$, let the symbol be the clock with its hand pointed at $\phi(r)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose an arbitrary set as symbols (the simplest way will be to take $\mathbb R$ itself), and you need a notation to write these symbols on paper - you can just say that symbol for number $123$ is written as $\overline{123}$ (and it is separate symbol, not a string $\bar{1} \bar 2 \bar 3$).

At this point word "symbol" has two meaning: the actual thing you write on paper / show on screen, and part of signature of theory, where it is element from arbitrary set, and we only need to distinguish it from other parts. You may need a notation to write (some) formulas on paper, and no notation will allow you to write arbitrary real number, but this is usually not a problem.

Comment: Thank you, but the exercise states that I should have a constant symbol for each real number?

Comment: You need constant symbols in the second sense (symbols are elements of some set, not written letters). You can declare $\mathbb R$ itself to be set of constant symbols (or any other set with the same cardinality).